# What is valid ID for purchasing alcohol in Baltimore, MD?

Tags: passports, paperwork, driving-licenses, alcohol, baltimore

I am traveling to Baltimore in July from the UK. I have been several times before, but I need to clarify some things for a few others.

I managed fine with my UK passport, however, as I have found out, MD's alcohol laws are devolved to the county level and finding info on what US IDs are valid has been a headache.

Some places seem to say military IDs are OK, others not.
MD issued IDs seem OK, but not those of other states unless it's a drivers license.
Then there seems to be an issue with 'vertical' IDs.
Then there seems to be rules about needing two types of ID.

All a bit confusing, any help would be welcome.

Comment: It won't be law enforcement officials checking your ID, but an employee or contractor of the bar, and in that sense, there is no ID you can carry that the establishment "must" accept. The [Baltimore CIty ABC](http://www.baltimorecity.gov/sites/default/files/Alcoholic%20Beverages%20Rules%20and%20Regulations.pdf) doesn't stipulate how the age of the patron is to be established, so in theory, the establishment could require a stamped long form birth certificate and smartphone clip of your birth video. For anyone without a US state or federal ID, a passport will be your safest bet.

Comment: Even if the state or county has a policy, every business is free to set their own requirements, so it pretty much comes down to the store and the clerk whether they'll sell to you.